# defining integrals with partition of unity

Tags: integration

I have a question about the following bit of text:
[image]
They say that $\int_A\phi\cdot\vert f\vert$ exists for each $\phi\in\Phi$. I don't see why this is the case. Since $\Phi$ is a subordinate cover, we know that for each $\phi$, there is a $U$ in $\mathcal O$, such that $\phi$ is zero outside some closed set $V$ contained in $U$. This means that our integral is reduced to
$$
\int_A\phi\cdot\vert f\vert=\int_V\phi\cdot\vert f\vert.
$$
However, they only say that $f$ is bounded in some open set, say $B$. Let's assume $B\subset V$. In that case, our integral still might not have a bounded integrand, so we might still have a problem. Could someone clarify why the integral exists?

Answer (score 1):

But as a part of partition of unity, $\phi\in C^{0}$ on the compact set $V$, so $\phi$ is bounded, then so is $\phi\cdot|f|$.

The whole story is like this: First choose compact set such that $\phi$ is supported in $V$. Now choose a finite subcover $\{G_{i}\}$ of $V$ such that $G_{i}\subseteq A$. Now by assumption $f$ is bounded on each $G_{i}$, and all such $G_{i}$ are finitely many, then a common upper bound is then obtained.

Comment: I am not familiar with $L^\infty$. Also, $\phi$ is $C^\infty$?

Comment: Yes, in particular, $\phi$ is continuous, this is what $C^{0}$ meant. $L^{\infty}$ in some sense means bounded.

Comment: So it's impossible to provide an argument without $L^\infty$?

Comment: Okay, like this: Choose $V$ as a compact set, then the continuous function $\phi$ on the compact set must be bounded, then the multiplication $\phi\cdot|f|$ is bounded too.

Comment: I never worried about $\phi$ not being bounded, I am worried about $\vert f\vert$ not being bounded, if $B\subset V$.

Comment: First, choose $V$ to be compact such that $\phi$ is supported in $V$, then find a finite subcover $\{G_{i}\}$ of $K$ and use the fact that $f$ is bounded on each $G_{i}$, this subcover is finite, the common bound can be obtained.

Comment: @user284331 Right. This is the point that OP is asking about.

Comment: I think I understand where my confusion lies. I don't see why $f$ would be bounded on each $G_i$. The assumption is that $f$ is bounded around each point in $A$, but how do we know it is bounded on some random $G_i$? The only thing we know about $G_i$ is that it is bounded.

Comment: @ShaVuklia:  For any $x \in V$ there is an open set $G_x$ containing $x$ where $f$ is bounded by hypothesis. Now $V \subset \cup_{x \in V} G_x$ and by compactness $V$ is covered by finitely many sets $G_{x_1}, \ldots, G_{x_n}$.  Since $f$ is bounded on each of these sets, $f$ is bounded on $V$.  Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2201399/148510